# Printing a Go type ignoring "String() string" method

Tags: interface, go, formatting, printf

If I have a type in go like this:

```
type myType ...

func (m myType) String() string { ... }
```

how can I print (using the various `fmt` functions) this type using the default representation (that is, instead of having `String()` called)? What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
func (m myType) String() string {
    // some arbitrary property
    if myType.isValid() {
        // format properly
    } else {
        // will recurse infinitely; would like default
        // representation instead
        return fmt.Sprintf("invalid myType: %v", m)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`fmt.Stringer` *is* the default format, which is called when you use `%v`. If you want the Go syntax, use `%#v`.

Alternatively, you can bypass the reflection in `fmt` altogether, and format your output as you see fit.

```
func (m myType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{Field: %s}", m.Value)
}
```

If the underlying type of myType is a number, string or other simple type, then convert to the underlying type when printing:

```
func (m mType) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(int(m))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `%#v` instead of `%v`

That will not invoke String(). - but it will invoke [GoString](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#GoStringer)() if you implement it.

Comment: This was covered in Effective Go. OP should convert the value to the underlying type and then use `%v` format. See my answer.

Comment: @Ainar-G Your answer is trivial for a type alias, but doesn't become straight forward for e.g. `type myType struct { a myOtherType}`. There also doesn't seem to be anything in Effective Go that indicates %#v is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Using `%#v` format is not the correct answer if you want to get your underlying type's `String` to work or your type is a type alias.

As is explained in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing), just convert it back to the type it represents:

```
type Foo int

func (f Foo) String() string {
    if f == 0 {
        return "foo"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", int(f)) // N.B.
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Foo(0))
    fmt.Println(Foo(42))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dWIQbPqfr6).

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out in the comments, if your type is a struct, using `%#v` format seems like the only way besides converting it to an anonymous struct type with same fields.

Comment: This only really helps though if `myType` is a type alias. More frequently it's a struct itself.

Comment: Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve explicit conversion? My use case is that I have a struct, and it'd be a pain to create an anonymous version of it just for printing and then convert between the two.